# fputs creating a problem

Tags: c, file

```
fseek(ofile, 13, SEEK_SET);
fputs("\t", ofile);

do
{
     ch = getc(ofile);
     printf("%c", ch);

     if(ch == '\n') {
         fseek(ofile, 13, SEEK_CUR);
         fputs("\t", ofile);
     }
} while(ch != EOF);
```

I have written this program which manipulates a file and inserts a \t after a particular position in each line.
Whenever I use second fputs it makes file unreadable. Why is this happening?

Comment: Note that in your if statement, if(ch == '\n') then you are calling getc twice in succession - once in the body of the 'if', and then a second time at the top of the 'do' block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things you may want to look at:

- `fputs` doesn't *insert* anything, it *overwrites* whatever was there. In other words, that <kbd>TAB</kbd> character will simply overwrite whatever was originally there. If you want to insert things, you're better off writing a filter-type program which copies characters from one file to another, allowing changes along the way (like inserting if the last newline was 13 characters ago, for example).
- Your `fseek` will change the current position for both writing *and* subsequent `getc` operations. That means you need to watch out for lines shorter than you expect.
- You really should check the return values from `fseek` and `fputs` - it is possible that they may fail.
- After a `getc`, the file pointer is at the *next* character, so make sure it's the one fourteen characters after the newline that you're interested in.
- Watch out for the final newline in the file. It's unlikely that the seek 13 bytes beyond that will work and you're doing an `fputs` anyway.

Failing all that, dump out the modified file in hex mode with something like the Linuxy:

```
od -xcb myFileName.txt
```

and see what the individual bytes are. `gEdit` is notorious for rejecting files which even have one character out of whack, which is why I use `vim` for everything :-)

Comment: fseek and fputs both are working. File is manipulated as I want but it doesn't open with text editor. I think its addinng something to the file that is the cause of whole problem

Comment: Don't take offence, @Shweta, you came here looking for help. If you don't _want_ help, I can apply my efforts somewhere else, just let me know. The reason I included that is _because_ you used the word `insert`. I have no idea what the structure of your data is since you didn't provide that detail.

Comment: I am sorry for the harsh answer but I didn't mean to offend you

Comment: @Shweta: no problems, consider it forgotten. It's unusual for the file to not open in a text editor though. Is it just crashing the editor? Does the editor give an error of any sort? Which text editor is it?

Comment: @Shweta, I've added something else to check. If the final character in the file is a newline, the seek will probably fail and you will be doing `fputs` after the final character. Not _entirely_ certain what will happen in that case.

Comment: Text editor is giving erro:gedit has not been able to detect the character coding.
Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.
Select a character coding from the menu and try again

Comment: The fseek is not failing. I have checked